# Negating inequalities of linear expressions of integers while only using "or equal" relations.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, integers, polyhedra

I'm trying to negate linear inequalities of integers while only using X-or-equal relationships; e.g. $\neg (n \geq 0) = (n \leq -1)$.

While the example with a single variable is trivial, how do you negate a more complex example ?

For instance, is it true that $\neg(n_1 + 3n_2\geq 1) = (n_1 + 3n_2 \leq 0)$ ? Is the formula simply $\neg(\textit{expr} \geq n) = (\textit{expr} \leq n-1)$
?
Thank you.

Comment: It is true, if $n_1,n_2  \in \mathbb Z.$

Comment: I have added a more precise question of what I want. Also, is there a proof that it works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an additional constraint that $n_1,n_2\in \mathbb Z$. If yes, this is fine. If not and your variables may be arbitrary reals, I think a possible way without using the $<$ or $>$ symbols would be:

$$\neg(a_1n_1+b_1n_2\geq c) \equiv \exists x> 0 \textrm{ such that } a_1n_1+b_1n_2+x\leq c.\tag{1}$$

This works in the integer case as well, because $\mathbb Z$ is contained in $\mathbb R$.

This is also a more general negation, because the true negation is actually
$$a_1n_1+b_1n_2 < c,$$
which may be alternatively written as the RHS of $(1)$.

What happens when you restrict to $\mathbb Z$ is that your $x$ is at least $1$, so you get

$$a_1n_1+b_1n_2+1\leq c\Rightarrow a_1n_1+b_1n_2\leq c -1 .$$

Possibly of interest and somewhat related:

1. [Open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Definitions)
2. [Slack variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable)